# Как цикл в программе заменить на list comprehensions

Tags: python

```
alpha = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'  
message = input('Введите сообщение: ')  
step = int(input('Введите сдвиг: '))  
result = '' 

for i in message:
  place = alpha.find(i)  
  new_place = place + step  
  if i in alpha:
    result += alpha[new_place] 
  else:
    result += i

print('Зашифрованное сообщение:', result)
```

Comment: `result = ''.join([alpha[alpha.find(char) + step] for char in message])`

Answer (score 0):

```py
alpha = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'  
message = input('Введите сообщение: ')  
step = int(input('Введите сдвиг: '))  
result = '' 

result = ''.join(alpha[alpha.find(i) + step] if i in alpha else i for i in message)
print('Зашифрованное сообщение:', result)
```

Comment: Спасибо, join еще ни разу не использовала. посмотрю что это такое

Comment: X_X Да, реализация шифра Цезаря никуда, здесь нужно через %, а "двойной алфавит" — моветон. Но сам однострочник построен грамотно.